# Swift Cannot touch Button in UIPickerView

Tags: swift, button, uipickerview, toolbar

here is my question

I set a popup pickerview and add toolBar in the top
but I can't touch or click button on top of UIPickerView

Everything is ok include set up a PickerView and top of Button

```
    self.view.addSubview(pickerView)
    self.pickerView.addSubview(toolBar)
```

this two code is working in my view and can select but cannot click the done button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGTYl.png)

how can Coding that can click??

i have Tried "userInteractionEnabled" and "willMoveToSuperview"
it doesn't work

plz someone help me.... thanks

All Code is  here

```
    import UIKit

    class AddNew: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {  


    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!    

    var pickerViewList = ["one","two","three","four","five"]

    var pickerView = UIPickerView()

    var toolBar = UIToolbar()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target:self, action:#selector(AddNew.hideMypicker))

    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action:#selector(AddNew.hideMypicker))

    cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerViewList.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerViewList[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    display.text = pickerViewList[row]
}

@IBAction func ClickButton(sender: UIButton) {
    self.pickerView.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
    self.pickerView.bounds  = CGRectMake(0, self.pickerView.bounds.origin.y, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, self.pickerView.bounds.height)
    self.pickerView.frame.origin.x = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3){
        self.pickerView.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height - self.pickerView.frame.height
    }
    self.view.addSubview(pickerView)
    self.pickerView.addSubview(toolBar)
}

func hideMypicker(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3,animations:{self.pickerView.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height},completion:{(value:Bool) in self.twofunction()})
}



func twofunction() {
    pickerView.removeFromSuperview()
    toolBar.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Please show the toolBar and pickerView initialization codes

Comment: What @ChathurangaSilva said, and I'd be suspicious if the button's action just isn't hooked up properly.

Comment: Hare your more code , so that context becomes more clear line how action to button is assigned etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a custom ActionSheetPickerView subclass it of UIControl? There you can set the PickerViewDataSource and PickerViewDelegate methods there so that u can use the same wherever u need the pickerView.

Create a ActionSheetPickerViewDelegate (custom delegate) defining the methods for doneButtonTap under the optional section.

The code would become much cleaner and easier to debug. Now coming back to your code, have you tried debugging using view debugger??